# Jquery Animate no works

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I create function for mouseover elements and move from one menu of my website

```
<script>

function cp_menu(id,status)
{

if(status=="no")
{
var url="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/core/imagenes/mod_register/"+id+".png";
jQuery("."+id).attr("src",url);
}
else
{
var url="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/core/imagenes/mod_register/"+id+"_over.png";
jQuery("."+id).attr("src",url);


jQuery("."+id).animate({

left:"-30",

},1000);


}

}

</script>
```

The problem it´s with animate and no works , no move to the top some pixels , only that

I call script with this :

```
<img src="image.png" class="dominios" onmouseover="cp_menu('number_1','yes')" onmouseout="cp_menu('number_1','no');">
```

Thank´s Regards !

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try changing `left:"-30",` to `left:"-30px",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `"` for left, also remove `,`.

```
jQuery("."+id).animate({

"left":"-=30px"

},1000);
```

Also

```
jQuery("."+id)  // there is no id like number_1
```

Hence animate is not working

maybe try this

```
jQuery(this).animate({"left": "-30px"}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class name you're passing in as a parameter is different from the image's actual class.

Try changing your code to this:

```
<img src="image.png" class="dominios" onmouseover="cp_menu('dominios','yes')" onmouseout="cp_menu('dominios','no');">
```